# Verilog VGA buffer not working as intended

Tags: buffer, verilog, fpga, vga

I'm trying to use a buffer to make the animation smoother in my current project.
I was able to implement it properly without buffers with the player character moving smoothly. But for some reason with this implementation the player character only moves like once in 5 to 10 seconds.

I tried simulating and looking at the waves but so far the waves seem find and does not explain why the screen is refreshing slowly. It refreshes slow but it is drawn perfectly without any flashing.

Here is the code for buffer that is probably causing the problem,

```
module m_engine
(
  input  wire        CLK100MHZ,
  input  wire [4:0]  BTN,
  input  wire [15:0] SW,
  output wire [6:0]  SG,
  output wire [7:0]  AN,
  output wire [15:0] LED,
  output wire        VGA_HS,
  output wire        VGA_VS,
  output reg  [3:0]  VGA_R,
  output reg  [3:0]  VGA_G,
  output reg  [3:0]  VGA_B
);
  /****************************************************************************/
  // Simulation
  /****************************************************************************/
  // reg CLK100MHZ = 0, r_display_clock = 0;
  // initial forever #1 CLK100MHZ = ~CLK100MHZ;
  // initial forever #2 r_display_clock = ~r_display_clock;
  //
  // assign w_display_clock = r_display_clock;
  /****************************************************************************/

  /****************************************************************************/
  // Display
  /****************************************************************************/
  wire        w_display_clock;
  wire [10:0] w_display_x;
  wire [10:0] w_display_y;
  wire        w_display_active;
  wire        w_display_reset;
  wire        w_display_frame;
  reg  [11:0] r_display_out;

  CLK40MHZ display_clock (w_display_clock, CLK100MHZ);
  assign w_display_reset = SW[15];
  always @ (posedge CLK100MHZ)
  begin
    if (w_display_active)
    begin
      VGA_R <= r_display_out[11:8];
      VGA_G <= r_display_out[7:4];
      VGA_B <= r_display_out[3:0];
    end
    else
    begin
      VGA_R <= 0;
      VGA_G <= 0;
      VGA_B <= 0;
    end
  end

  m_vga display
  (
    .iw_clock  (w_display_clock),
    .iw_rst    (w_display_reset),
    .ow_hs     (VGA_HS),
    .ow_vs     (VGA_VS),
    .ow_x      (w_display_x),
    .ow_y      (w_display_y),
    .ow_active (w_display_active),
    .ow_frame  (w_display_frame)
  );
  /****************************************************************************/

  /****************************************************************************/
  // VRAM
  /****************************************************************************/
  localparam DISPLAY_WIDTH   = 800;
  localparam DISPLAY_HEIGHT  = 600;
  localparam VRAM_DEPTH      = DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
  localparam VRAM_ADDR_WIDTH = 19;
  localparam VRAM_DATA_WIDTH = 4;

  reg  [VRAM_ADDR_WIDTH - 1:0] r_vram_address;
  wire [VRAM_DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] w_vram0_dataout, w_vram1_dataout;
  reg  [VRAM_DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] r_vram_datain;
  reg                          r_vram_write = 0;

  always @(posedge CLK100MHZ)
  begin
    r_vram_address <= w_display_y * DISPLAY_WIDTH + w_display_x;
    // Display content of active VRAM
    r_display_out = (r_vram_write) ? w_vram1_dataout : w_vram0_dataout;
  end

  // At the end of every frame switch buffers.
  always @(posedge w_display_frame)
    r_vram_write = ~r_vram_write;

  m_sram
  #(
    .ADDR_WIDTH (VRAM_ADDR_WIDTH),
    .DATA_WIDTH (VRAM_DATA_WIDTH),
    .DEPTH      (VRAM_DEPTH)
  )
  vram0
  (
    .iw_addr  (r_vram_address),
    .iw_clock (CLK100MHZ),
    .iw_write (r_vram_write),
    .or_data  (w_vram0_dataout),
    .iw_data  (r_vram_datain)
  );

  m_sram
  #(
    .ADDR_WIDTH (VRAM_ADDR_WIDTH),
    .DATA_WIDTH (VRAM_DATA_WIDTH),
    .DEPTH      (VRAM_DEPTH)
  )
  vram1
  (
    .iw_addr  (r_vram_address),
    .iw_clock (CLK100MHZ),
    .iw_write (!r_vram_write),
    .or_data  (w_vram1_dataout),
    .iw_data  (r_vram_datain)
  );
  /****************************************************************************/

  /****************************************************************************/
  // Game Logic
  /****************************************************************************/
  reg [10:0] r_player_x = 400, r_player_y = 300;
  wire w_player_draw;
  wire [VRAM_DATA_WIDTH - 1:0] w_player_dataout;

  m_entity
  #(
    .ADDR_WIDTH  (VRAM_ADDR_WIDTH),
    .DATA_WIDTH  (VRAM_DATA_WIDTH),
    .ENTITY_SIZE (32),
    .MEMFILE("fighter.mem")
  )
  player
  (
    .iw_clock  (CLK100MHZ),
    .iw_draw_x (w_display_x),
    .iw_draw_y (w_display_y),
    .iw_pos_x  (r_player_x),
    .iw_pos_y  (r_player_y),
    .ow_draw   (w_player_draw),
    .or_data   (w_player_dataout)
  );

  reg [11:0] r_player_palette [0:255];
  initial
  begin
    $display("Loading sprite r_player_palette.");
    $readmemh("fighter_palette.mem", r_player_palette);
  end

  reg [20:0] r_i = 0;
  always @(posedge CLK100MHZ)
  begin
    // Player control
    r_i <= r_i + 1;
    if(r_i == 0)
    begin
      if (BTN[3] && r_player_x < DISPLAY_WIDTH - 32)
        r_player_x <= r_player_x + 1;
      if (BTN[2] && r_player_x > 0)
        r_player_x <= r_player_x - 1;
      if (BTN[4] && r_player_y < DISPLAY_HEIGHT - 32)
        r_player_y <= r_player_y + 1;
      if (BTN[1] && r_player_y > 0)
        r_player_y <= r_player_y - 1;
    end

    // Player draw
    if      (w_player_draw) r_vram_datain <= w_player_dataout;
    else                    r_vram_datain <= 12'b111111111;
  /****************************************************************************/
endmodule
```

And one more thing, the background is supposed to be white because I input 111111111111 into VGA when not drawing the player but for some reason the screen is blue. I'm not sure what's causing it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I somehow solved it by myself again. It turns out that the clock frequency for the VRAM has to match the display in order to work properly. Not it's working so smoothly that its unbelievable!

Also, found out why the background was turning blue. I forgot that I reduced the data width for my VRAM because I ran out of MUX. So basically, the VRAM was only outputting 4 bits and that was the cause of the blue background.